# JavaScript window.location.href code not working

Tags: javascript

I know this question has been asked a lot before, but none of the fixes worked for me. I made a window.location. href thing before and that worked but this one does not. I know the function runs because I tested it with an alert. Can someone see anything wrong here?

```
<form>

    <input type="submit" name="agree" value="agree" onclick="fagree()">
    <input type="submit" name="disagree" value="Decline and go to google" onclick="fdisagree()">

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function fagree(){
window.location.assign("index.html")
localStorage.setItem("Terms", "true")
}
function fdisagree(){
window.location.href="https://www.google.com/"
return false;
}
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `button` type instead of submit, otherwise, well, the form will be submit.

```
<form>
    <input type="button" name="agree" value="agree" onclick="fagree()">
    <input type="button" name="disagree" value="Decline and go to google" onclick="fdisagree()">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function fagree(){
    window.location.assign("index.html");
    localStorage.setItem("Terms", "true"); //This line won't be executed, because the above line will reload the page
}

function fdisagree() {
    window.location.href="https://www.google.com/"
    return false; //This can be removed because the above line will redirect to google and the return false won't be executed
}
</script>
```

If you don't need any else `form` elements than those 2 buttons, you can get ride of the `<form></form>` and simply use `<button>`. In example :

```
<button type="button" name="agree" value="agree" onclick="fagree()">
<button type="button" name="disagree" value="Decline and go to google" onclick="fdisagree()">
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not put it in the form if you don't have to (if that's the whole form code in the example). You are submitting it before functions have a chance to trigger.

OR:

```
<form>

    <input type="button" name="agree" value="agree" onclick="fagree()">
    <input type="button" name="disagree" value="Decline and go to google" onclick="fdisagree()">

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function fagree(){
window.location.assign("index.html")
localStorage.setItem("Terms", "true")
}
function fdisagree(){
window.location.href="https://www.google.com/"
return false;
}
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: ok thx so if i understood that right make the <button> outside a form?

Comment: Oh nvm i fixed it by making it a button